# Building spark notebook for windows with sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-notebook

Can spark notebook be built with Windows ?

I've checked out latest source and run via 'sbt run' but receive error :

```
workspaces\spark-notebook-master\app\Global.scala:11: object share is not a member of package notebook
[error]           notebook.share.Tachyon.start
```

I've disable tachyon from the application.conf file, but this does not fix building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I get compilation errors on master but using version 0.6.2 compiles and runs without issue : https://github.com/andypetrella/spark-notebook/tree/v0.6.2